# More than one session from the same browser

Tags: jsf, session

I need a little direction understanding sessions in JSF (2.2.6). I've tried to find some documentation but am still missing something.

I have a @RequestScoped login bean which saves parameters in the session map for reference by other session scoped backing beans. They get the user info when they go through the PostConstruct method and everything works great.

However the logic fails when more than one window is used or the user doesn't logoff and goes directly back to the login page. JSF treats this as the same session and the @PostConstructs are not invoked.

I am pretty sure I could invalidate the session but that doesn't solve the problem of multiple users from different browser windows.

Any guidance or reference sites would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!
John

Comment: I just don't get how you are using the post construct here. Isn't it supposed to be called before you process the user input?

Comment: One browser == one session! by definition. JBoss Seam 'conversations' are a solution to this, but a clumsy one.

Comment: @Leo the login authentication is processed by my login bean which then uses the return string to navigate to another page. The render of that page occurs in a SessionScoped bean.

Comment: @EJP you are probably right but I tested with other apps and they handle this fine. As to the user just hot linking back to login. Should I use session.invalidate() or what is best to handle that.

Comment: why not login directly in session bean? however a session exists even if user is not logged in.

Comment: @Michele I can see how that would help my login bean but what about the others?  I presumed that with SessionScoped persisting my bean properties then PostConstruct was the right place to set the user info. However if session!=OneBrowserWindow then I am not sure how a client with two active windows and jsf with only one externalContext and component map will provide reliable responses. I must misunderstand something.

Comment: Injection simplifies things but I also used the PostConstruct to inform the Stateless EJB of the user, i.e. ejb.startSession(user) - does that make sense?  The bank I use doesn't seem to limit one user per browser but Google does. I can live with it but there is also a security issue as my session stays alive unless I formally logoff and most users don't! Skipping the login page for existing sessions exposes the problem but invalidating the session if a different user would be a bad user experience when multiple windows are in use. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

session HAS to be same for every browser window, the only exception is when using anonymous mode: i.e. chrome behave like having two browsers opened at the same time.

another way to have multiple sesssions is to use different server name:
`http://localhost:8080/app` and `http://127.0.0.1:8080/app` may not share a single session.

however sessions never overlaps.

your problem, if i understand right, is when a logged user access login page and **re-login**, preserving his old session, that's why session beans are not PostConstructed again (independently from window used).

a general solution is to forbid access to login page for logged users.
and in general, container will throw an AlreadyAuthenticatedException or similar when user re-login without prior logout.

cut a long story short, just a preliminary example waiting for your code:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private User user;

    public boolean isLoggedIn()
    {
        return user != null;
    }

    public void login(String username, String password)
    {
        // maybe you want to check isLoggedIn() and either call logout() or throw an exception

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
        request.login(username, password);

        user = someDAO.loadFromDatabase(username); 
    }

    public void logout()
    {
        // maybe you want to check isLoggedIn() and either throw an exception or do nothing

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
        request.logout();

        user = null;

        // suggested for another scenario
        // request.getSession().invalidate();
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

and

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class OperationBean implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ManagedProperty("#{userBean}")
    private UserBean userBean;

    public void execute()
    {
        if(!userBean.isLoggedIn())
        {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("login.jsf");
            return;
        }

        User user = userBean.getUser();

        // do something 
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

with this combination, instead of using OperationBean's @PostContruct i used @ManagedProperty, so that OperationBean contains an always-up-to-date reference to user, without caring multiple re-logins.